# I want to display several youtube videos on the same screen with react-native-youtube

Tags: react-native, youtube

I'm doing kids app with tales(text + images) and youtube videos
For one screen I want to display list of youtube videos. I'm using react-native-youtube to display youtube on the one page and it works fine but when I place several instances of react-native-youtube with different videoId it displays only last video on all instances.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ImageBackground, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import YouTube from 'react-native-youtube';

function YoutubePage({ navigation }){    
    
    return(
            <ScrollView style={styles.ImageBg}>
                <View style={styles.paragraph}>
                    <Text style={styles.ContentTxt}>1. Цап та баран</Text>
                    <View><YouTube videoId="7Qrj0ZUDDeI" apiKey="#" style={styles.YouTubePageContainerWrapper} /></View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.paragraph}>
                    <Text style={styles.ContentTxt}>2. Рак-неборак та його вірна жінка</Text>
                    <View><YouTube videoId="HuvZ9n1qzik" apiKey="#" style={styles.YouTubeContainerWrapper} /></View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.paragraph}>
                    <Text style={styles.ContentTxt}>3. Колобок</Text>
                    <View><YouTube videoId="hFIDonaIly8" apiKey="#" style={styles.YouTubeContainerWrapper} /></View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.paragraph}>
                    <Text style={styles.ContentTxt}>4. Пан Коцький</Text>
                    <View><YouTube videoId="a40_muK0iDU" apiKey="#" style={styles.YouTubeContainerWrapper} /></View>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create(defaultStyles);

export default YoutubePage;
```

is there way to display different youtube videos on the same screen with react-native-youtube?

Comment: This is a known limitation of react-native-youtube. (you cannot have two different youtube vidoes on the same screen). Please try other alternative :https://surajmdurgad.medium.com/embedding-youtube-videos-in-a-react-native-app-8c556a18fd76

Comment: @KenLee, you might be right... I've switched to react-native-webview but I don't like how it displays videos. react-native-youtube is much better:(